# PowerShell script that searches for a string in txt , collect them and compare between all files

Tags: powershell

I have many files that contains an ID and I need to get all the IDs and compare to the rest of the files and show if there are same IDs.
What I am looking for is Package ID="" ,Could be more than one in the same file, each file contains also a similar string but without space (PackageID='' that I don't need to collect
I started with:

```
$seedMatches = Select-String -Path "C:\Temp\vip.manifest" -Pattern "Package ID"
```

[image]

Comment: Is there always only 1 appearance of `<Package ID="...."` per file ? I mean specifically with the space

Comment: Could be more than one Package ID=“”

Comment: please don't post images of code/errors/data. why? lookee ... Why should I not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? - Meta Stack Overflow — https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this, unfortunately, if there can be more than one appearance of `Package ID` you would need to read the full content of the file. You can use a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-7.2) with the `-Regex` parameter to search for the [`Guid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.tostring?view=net-6.0) and `-File` parameter to read the file:

```
$initialPath = 'path/to/filemanifests'
$guidmap = foreach($file in Get-ChildItem $initialPath -Filter *.manifest) {
    switch -Regex -File($file) {
        '(?<=<Package ID=")(?<guid>[\d\w-]+)"' {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                Guid = $Matches['guid']
                Path = $file.FullName
            }
            # if you only need the first appearance of the Guid
            # you can add a `break` here to stop searching
        }
    }
}

$guidmap | Group-Object Guid | Where-Object Count -GT 1 | ForEach-Object Group
```

Comment: Don't recommend regular expressions to parse XML. This is generally true, doubly so to newbies who hardly know what they are doing.

Comment: Thanks Santiago can you help me with the rest of my question please? How to compare between many files and catch if there duplicate IDs

Comment: @Bandit the last line on my answer should be doing that, group all results by the captured GUID and outputting only those which appear 2 or more times (duplicates)

Comment: I will update my answer, please let me know if your answer can be valid also with this case: each manifest is located in zip file and the folder contains many zips, so I am running in a loop for each one of the zips and extract to temp folder. What should I do in this case?

Comment: @Bandit no, this answer is not meant to read all files in a zip you should ask a new question for that